# How to urlencode location.search params in IE7, using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, urlencode

I have noticed that IE7 does not url-encode querystring parameters retrieved from javascript, e.g:

```
var qs = location.search;
```

In Firefox, the parameters are encoded. How can I write IE-specific code to URL-encode the parameters in the same fashion as FireFox?

For example, in Firefox, this querystring:

```
?val=<script>

//gets rewritten as:

?val=%3Cscript%3E
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, the correct function to URL-encode a string for use in part of a URL is `encodeURIComponent`. *Don't* use `escape`, which is an obsolescent non-standard custom encoding scheme unique to JavaScript. It looks like URL-parameter-encoding, but treats pluses and all non-ASCII characters differently. Put it together with a standard URL decoder and you get errors.

However, you shouldn't call `encodeURIComponent` over `location.search` if it's giving you bad characters like `<` or `>` (which shouldn't appear in a URL, but which IE allows you to enter), because it will double-encode characters that are already correctly encoded; for example a real `%3C` in the address (from if the user has followed a *correctly*-formed link to your site) will get mis-converted to `%253C`.

Fixing up ‘unsafe’ URL characters whilst leaving already-encoded characters alone is what the `encodeURI` function is for; try that (on all browsers, no need for sniffing). It's rarely used, but could be what you need. Otherwise, you're looking at an annoying regexp-and-hex-encoding-function replacement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [escape](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp) function:

```
var qs = escape(location.search);
```

Comment: Don't use `escape`, it doesn't support UTF-8 encoding.  Use `encodeURIComponent` instead.